# Multiple TextBox and ComboBox Search in Windows Form Application C# using MS-Access

Tags: c#, sql, ms-access

I am having trouble in creating multiple `TextBox` and `ComboBox`search.

I used the following Query first:

```
SELECT p.property_id, p.property_name, s.type_name, p.property_purpose, p.property_price, p.area, p.bedrooms, p.property_location, c.customer_name, c.customer_mobile1
FROM (tb_property AS p INNER JOIN lk_tb_property_type AS s ON p.property_type_id=s.property_type_id) INNER JOIN tb_customer AS c ON p.customer_id=c.customer_id
WHERE ([@propertyType] Is Null Or s.type_name Like '%'+[@propertyType]+'%') And ([@propertyPurpose] Is Null Or p.property_purpose Like '%'+[@propertyPurpose]+'%') And ([@area] Is Null Or p.area Like '%'+[@area]+'%') And ([@bedrooms] Is Null Or p.bedrooms Like '%'+[@bedrooms]+'%') And ([@price] Is Null Or p.property_price Like '%'+[@price]+'%') And ([@buidName] Is Null Or p.property_name Like '%'+p.property_name+'%') And ([@location] Is Null Or p.property_location Like '%'+[@location]+'%');
```

When which when I am running in query wizard in MS-Access, what it is doing is when I dont pass any parameter to it i.e all parameters null it displays all contents. And the moment I pass single parameter it ain't giving me anything, just displays blank table.
And the moment I use this query using `CommandText` and pass the parameters using `Parameters.Add` I am getting `error` that *one or more parameter is missing*.

Can anybody provide me the solution that what is the way of doing search in MS-Access DB

I have used the same type of query in SQL Server which gives proper results.

I am using the following c# code:

```
string propertyType = combo_prop_type.Text;
if (propertyType == "Select Property Type")
{
    propertyType = null;
}
else
{
    propertyType = combo_prop_type.Text;
}

string propertyPurpose = combo_purpose.Text;
if (propertyPurpose == "Select Property Purpose")
{
    propertyPurpose = null;
}
else
{
    propertyType = combo_prop_type.Text;
}

string area = combo_area.Text;
if (area == "Select Area")
{
    area = null;
}
else
{
    area = combo_area.Text.ToString();
}

string bedrooms = combo_bedrooms.Text;
if (bedrooms == "Select Bedrooms")
{
    bedrooms = null;
}
else
{
    bedrooms = combo_bedrooms.Text.ToString();
}

string price = combo_price.Text;
if (price == "Select Price")
{
    price = null;
}
else
{
    price = combo_price.Text.ToString();
}

string buidName = txt_build_name.Text.Trim();
string location = txt_location.Text.Trim();

OleDbConnection con = new OleDbConnection(constr);
OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand();

cmd.Connection = con;
cmd.CommandText = "select p.property_id, p.property_name, s.type_name, p.property_purpose, p.property_price, p.area, p.property_location, c.customer_name, c.customer_mobile1  from ((tb_property p INNER JOIN lk_tb_property_type s ON p.property_type_id = s.property_type_id) INNER JOIN tb_customer c ON p.customer_id = c.customer_id) WHERE (@propertyType is null or s.type_name like '%' + @propertyType + '%') and (@propertyPurpose is null or p.property_purpose like '%'+ @propertyPurpose +'%') and (@area is null or p.area like '%'+ @area +'%') and (@bedrooms is null or p.bedrooms like '%'+ @bedrooms +'%') and (@price is null or p.property_price like '%'+ @price +'%') and (@buidName is null or p.property_name like '%'+ @buildName +'%') and (@location is null or p.property_location like '%'+ @location +'%')";
cmd.Parameters.Add("@propertyType", OleDbType.VarChar, 50).Value = propertyType;
cmd.Parameters.Add("@propertyPurpose", OleDbType.VarChar, 50).Value = propertyPurpose;
cmd.Parameters.Add("@area", OleDbType.VarChar, 50).Value = area;
cmd.Parameters.Add("@bedrooms", OleDbType.VarChar, 50).Value = bedrooms;
cmd.Parameters.Add("@price", OleDbType.VarChar, 50).Value = price;
cmd.Parameters.Add("@buildName", OleDbType.VarChar, 50).Value = buidName;
cmd.Parameters.Add("@location", OleDbType.VarChar, 50).Value = location;
cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
OleDbDataAdapter da = new OleDbDataAdapter();
da.SelectCommand = cmd;
DataSet ds = new DataSet();
da.Fill(ds);
for (int i = 0; i < ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count; i++)
{

    for (int j = 0; j < 9; j++)
    {
        dataGridView2.Rows.Add(new DataGridViewRow());
        dataGridView2.Rows[i].Cells[j].Value = ds.Tables[0].Rows[i][j].ToString();
    }
}
con.Close();
```

I have also searched that `IFF()` or `COALESCE()` or `NZ()` are the following functions to use when we need to send default value but for `COALESCE()` i am getting undefined function in `MS-ACCESS` and when I am using `IFF` the `OR` condition that when user provides nothing to the to the `TextBox` or `ComboBox` its showing nothing into the `DataGrid`. Its only working when user provides atleast some value to every `TextBox` or `ComboBox`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can not reference the same parameter twice in the query sentence. Because every time it refers a new parameter!

> [MSDN - OleDbCommand.Parameters](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.oledb.oledbcommand.parameters%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)
>
> The OLE DB .NET Provider does not support named parameters for passing
>   parameters to an SQL statement or a stored procedure called by an
>   OleDbCommand when CommandType is set to Text. In this case, the
>   question mark (?) placeholder must be used. For example:
>
> SELECT * FROM Customers WHERE CustomerID = ?
>
> Therefore, the order in which
>   OleDbParameter objects are added to the OleDbParameterCollection must
>   directly correspond to the position of the question mark placeholder
>   for the parameter in the command text.

Instead you will have to build the query and dynamic parameters according to your UI mode.

like this:

```
string propertyType = combo_prop_type.Text;
if (propertyType == "Select Property Type")
{
    propertyType = null;
}
else
{
    da.SelectCommand.CommandText += " AND s.type_name LIKE ? ";
    da.SelectCommand.Parameters.Add("", "%" + combo_prop_type.Text + "%");
}
```

Comment: Got your point sir. But still how can I ignore a particular parameter comparison  in where clause when user does'nt type/select anything ???

Comment: i added in my answer a way (not the most elegant).

Comment: when I am adding parameters dynamically, how should I make my main select query should i end it till where or i need to exclude where also?

Comment: your concept is elegant sir :).